# Is there a method to clone an array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, clone

This is my code :

```
var a=[1,2,3]
b=$.clone(a)
alert(b)
```

Doesn't jQuery have a 'clone' method? How can I clone an array using jQuery?

Comment: For Multidimensional Array cloning see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294703/multidimensional-array-cloning-using-javascript

Comment: Yes. jQuery has a clone method, and also extend with the deep parameter set to true. See http://api.jquery.com/clone/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ The quick and dirty option for small amounts of data is to use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original)). For large amounts of data, maybe you shouldn't be cloning?!

Comment: use spread operator

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Just use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```
a = [1];
b = a.slice();
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/ebuk5/

Comment: This is synonymous with `slice(0)` ?

Comment: Thanks meder. ....... The only thing to watch out for, is that Arrays are objects, so you can attach properties and methods... like `var a=[1,2,3]; a.foo = function() { alert(this); };` With `slice()` any attached properties and methods aren't copied, so you couldn't do `b.foo()`... I only bring it up, since jQuery's `.clone()` does include a deep copy option. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/B2LQL/ .......... But this is pretty much a corner case in the context of this question.

Comment: I guess my testing code was totally wrong. I uploaded a fiddle and it's working allright http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/ebuk5/. It's definitions also pointing out that it returns a copy, and not a reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice. I editted the your answer and added the fiddle to there.

Comment: Just watch out: This does a *shallow* copy. Not a deep copy. So any objects in the array are not copied, they are simply referenced.

Comment: @Ariel, so how do you do a deep copy?

Comment: @ArmanBimatov Sorry, I don't remember what I did. I think I just used an object instead. See: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-extend-modifies-but-not-replaces-array-properties-on-deep-copy

Comment: @Arman See the stringify option below. It's ugly but it works.

Answer (score 11):

What about the [jQuery.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) ?

```
copy = $.merge([], a);
```

Comment: This also does a shallow copy, and therefore is equivalent to the accepted answer.

Comment: @rych This is not equivalent, as it also works on array-like objects that don't have a .slice method (eg. NamedNodeMap).

Answer (score 7):

**Change**

**b=$.clone(a)** to **b=$(this).clone(a)** but it some time dont work

but is reported

http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/jquery-clone-bug-in-internet-explorer

**Solution** 
you use simple inbuilt clone function of javascript

```
var a=[1,2,3];
b=clone(a);
alert(b);

function clone(obj){
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
        return obj;
    var temp = obj.constructor();
    for(var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
    return temp;
}
```

-ConroyP

**A great alternative is**

```
 // Shallow copy
  var b = jQuery.extend({}, a);

  // Deep copy
  var b = jQuery.extend(true, {}, a);
```

-John Resig

**Check similar post**

- [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Japan- Extend is meant for Objects. Ur first func was also meant for Object.

Comment: Extend works great for an array too, just change empty object {} into an empty array [].

Comment: When I used extend() and passed in {}, it didn't work right. It might work if I pass in [] instead.

Answer (score 7):

This is how i've done it :

```
var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orgArray));
```

this will create a new deep copy not related to the first one (not a shallow copy).

also this obviously will not clone events and functions, but the good thing you can do it in one line and it can be used for any king of object (arrays, strings, numbers, objects ...)

Comment: This is obviously not the right option for a big, complex structure, but it's a pretty nice one-liner, and actually the approach I ended up taking.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 
Please use spread

```
let arrayCopy = [...myArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (!Array.prototype.clone) {
    Array.prototype.clone = function () {
        var arr1 = new Array();
        for (var property in this) {
            arr1[property] = typeof (this[property]) == 'object' ? this[property].clone() : this[property]
        }
        return arr1;
    }​
}
```

use as

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a;
a.push(4)
alert(b); // alerts [1,2,3,4]
//---------------///
var a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.clone();
a.push(4)
alert(b); // alerts [1,2,3]​
```

Comment: This is just in case you've attached other properties to the array in addition to the values in the array? (as opposed to  just using `slice(0)`)?

Comment: @Peter - `slice(0)` is good. I'm just showing another way of solving it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Array.concat:

```
var a=[1,2,3]
var b=[].concat(a);
```

Comment: Basically the same problem as using slice.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a=[1,2,3]
b=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```