# JavaScript create use backup array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just look at the code and you'll understand what I mean:

```
​var aBackup = [3, 4]; // backup array
​​var a = aBackup; // array to work with is set to backup array
a[0]--; // working with array..
a = aBackup; // array o work with will be rested
console.log(a);  // returns [2, 4] but should return [3, 4]
console.log(aBackup);​ // returns [2, 4] too​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​  but should return [3, 4] too
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a method to clone an array in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775480/is-there-a-method-to-clone-an-array-in-jquery) -- despite the term jQuery in the title/question, the solutions are not jQuery related.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry I'vent seen this duplicate. Everyone should vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make real copies of your Arrays instead of just using a reference:

```
var aBackup = [3, 4]; // backup array
var a = aBackup.slice(0); // "clones" the current state of aBackup into a
a[0]--; // working with array..
a = aBackup.slice(0); // "clones" the current state of aBackup into a 
console.log(a);  // returns [3, 4] 
console.log(aBackup); // returns [3, 4]
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for documentation on the `slice`-method

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't javascript uses pointer for arrays ? Should `​​var a = aBackup;` do a copy ? otherwise the results seems normal to me...

Answer (score 1):

An array is a reference type of object, so changes made to it will change the underlying value it points to, a and aBackup will point to the same value, and a change made to a will change aBackup aswell.

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you do this, you are not making a copy of the array, but infact a reference to the original array.

```
var a IS aBackup; // if you will
```

When you need to do is clone the backup array.