# jQuery $.extend - to extend an Array

Tags: jquery, cloning

Using the `$.extend` is working, but it returns an Object and not a native Array, so the `push()` won't work.
How can I extend an array, using the `jQuery.extend`?

```
var x =[1,2];
var y = $.extend({},x);
y.push(3) // fail
```

---

edit:
The array WILL contain objects, so - the `slice()` won't do the trick

Comment: @PranavCBalan well, that's what i wrote.. and this is my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a method to clone an array in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775480/is-there-a-method-to-clone-an-array-in-jquery)

Comment: No where it saying that it will return an array...

Comment: jQuery.extend(['c'], ['a','b']) works. Index 0 is overridden as 'a'. And index 1 is assigned 'b'. And the result is an instanceof Array. Although many inbuilt methods are getting added as properties on the resultant array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of jQuery at all use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method.

```
var x =[1,2];
var y = x.concat([3,4]);
y.push(3)
```

Comment: shame on me. you are correct. thanks. (too much of that JQ)

Comment: @yossi : glad to help you..... if you want to push the value array into an existing array then.... `[].push.apply(x, [1,2,3])` this will push the array values to `x`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the input object as an array.

```
jQuery.extend(['c'], ['a','b'])
```

Above works as expected. Index 0 is overridden as 'a'. And index 1 is assigned 'b'. And the result is an `instanceof Array`.

Although, many inbuilt methods are getting added as properties on the resultant array, which might get in the way sometimes.

[image]