# jQuery created new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have problem with jQuery array.

I want have two different array.

```
var main_array = []

function create_array(){

   main_array[0] = {id: 1, status: true, number: 10};
   main_array[1] = {id: 1, status: true, number: 16};
   main_array[2] = {id: 1, status: true, number: 20};

}

function change(array, key, number){

   array[key].number = number

}

create_array()

new_array = change(main_array, 0, 20); 

console.log(main_array)
```

In this situation I add an element in $main_array array and I want change number and create new array, but when I call change function my main_array is changed to.

I don't want change main_array number.

That's what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Why are you using dollar-signs as prefixes to non-jQuery variables? There is no use of jQuery in your code at all.

Comment: What is test()?

Comment: do you want a copy of the array and the change the value?

Comment: The array is given by reference. What you need to do in your change function is to create a new array and return the new array:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775480/is-there-a-method-to-clone-an-array-in-jquery

Comment: och sorry... test is change(...)

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Technically, all arguments are passed by value in JavaScript. It's just that objects don't pass as objects, they are passed as a memory location reference, which a copy is then made of (by value).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects and when you pass an object to a function, you are passing a reference to the memory location of the object, not a copy of the object. So, if the receiving function modifies the incoming argument, it will modify the original object.

Because your array ***contains*** objects, they too are passed as references to the underlying object memory locations, you will need to create copies of each object in the array. This is done with **[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**.

Also (as I mentioned in my comment), prefixing identifiers with a dollar sign is generally considered a convention to denote the identifier holds a reference to a JQuery wrapped set object. Since you are not using JQuery anywhere in your code, I would advise you remove them.

```js
var main_array = [];  // <-- This is where the main array will go
var newArray =   [];  // <-- This will be where the copied array goes

function create_array(){

   main_array[0] = {id: 1, status: true, number: 10};
   main_array[1] = {id: 1, status: true, number: 16};
   main_array[2] = {id: 1, status: true, number: 20};
   
   return main_array;
}

function change(array, key, number){
   // Loop thorugh the original array:
   main_array.forEach(function(obj){
    // Make a copy of the objects in the array and put them in the new array
    newArray.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
   });
   newArray[key].number = number
}

main_array = create_array();

change(main_array, 0, 20); 

console.log(main_array, newArray)
```

Comment: @sinisake Just as I wrote it.

Comment: Yep, in first demo/output, both arrays were changed, again, so i was confused... :)