# Multi-dimension Array reference pro­blem

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

So currently I have an Array here, and I want to make some modification of the last item and push it back it. Here I have this code: (example is simplified)

```
var array = [
                 [ [0,1,2], [3,4,5] ]
            ];

//other stuff...

var add = array[0].slice(); //to clone the array (but not working as expected)
add[0][0] = 10;
array.push(add);

console.log(array);
```

And here's the result

[image]

As you can see, both the 1st and 2nd item have its first item changed to `10`. How can I solve this problem? I have already cloned the array.

Comment: What is slice supposed to do with no args

Comment: @aaronman - It is a trick used to clone arrays.

Comment: Yeah figured it out, you realize the problem is that the objects inside are references not new objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#article-nav) does shallow copy, so nested array are not copied. You should use deep clone method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294703/multidimensional-array-cloning-using-javascript).

Comment: Ur answer is good but it would be nice if you spoke on the point that the array created by slice is new but the objects inside the original array are not copied but references

Comment: @aaronman Agree. I think "shallow copy" explains it all, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.slice() does not clone nested array. you can do something like this particular to your problem

```
var array = [
                 [ [0,1,2], [3,4,5] ]
            ];

//other stuff...

var add = array[0].slice(); //to clone the array (but not working as expected)
add[0] = array[0][0].slice();
add[0][0] = 10;
array.push(add);

console.log(array);
```